# This bag of legos has two gears and is labled #2

Tags: set-identification

This bag of legos has two gears and is labled #2
What set would they go with?

[image]

Comment: At first glance, looks like some sort of ship.

Comment: This set of yours has already been identified. Please read and think before asking so many questions.